# C# Winforms control - DataGridView - Update Database

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview, sql-update

The programs I am using are WAMP server (and its mysql feature in particular) and MS Visual Studio 2010 and I am programming in C#

Basically, here is what I need and can currently do with my application.

I have several `datagridview`'s throughout the project and the first is simple, it loads all data from a specific table in the database at the push of a button. I have another form which I can insert records and have somehow managed to make a delete function which asks the user for 2 fields (first name and last name) and then it places these into a query and carries out the command.

What do I need to do?

I need to be able to implement some way for the form to update the database. I have chosen to do this through a `datagridview` control so the user can see what they are editting whilst they edit it.

I have the following code which I have tried to update the database based on the data in the `datagridview` control.

```
string connString = "server=localhost;User Id=root;database=collegelist;";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM collegeemployee";
conn.Open();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectSQL, conn);
MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
DataTable table = new DataTable(); 
try
{
    dgView2.Rows.RemoveAt(dgView2.CurrentRow.Index);
    da.Update(table);
}
catch (Exception exceptionObj)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exceptionObj.Message.ToString());
}
```

the problem with this code (listed in a method obviously) is that while the grid is able to be modified, it is unable to pass the data back to the database.

Comment: Why are you trying to update an empty table? What is the name of your bindingsource or data source ? i prefer to do the binding in code, it makes updates easier.

Comment: I have a button which retrieves the data from the database and fills the datagridview. Then this code is to submit the changes to the database. If I set the data source to early, the other tables won't show

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating your database with the empty table what you should do is.
i.Get the datasource . like
ii. Update/synchronize the data source and data adapter
Here is the code it should work, if it doesn't please comment and tell me the problem.

```
string connString = "server=localhost;User Id=root;database=collegelist;";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM collegeemployee";
conn.Open();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectSQL, conn);
MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
    BindingSource BindingSourceToUpdate = (BindingSource)dgView2.DataSource; // because direct casting to data table was failing in VS2o1o

                 try
                {
    dgView2.Rows.RemoveAt(dgView2.CurrentRow.Index);

                    da.Update((DataTable)BindingSourceToUpdate.DataSource);
                }
                catch(exception)
                 {
                 }
conn.close();
```

Comment: I'll have a go. Cheers. Btw I have made it so when you press a button to select data from a table, the sets the binding source.